# Parsing JSON file using Lambda

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, parsing, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My main objective is to parse a JSON file and write the content of the JSON file to a scrollable list in the browser. I created a JSON file and stored it in an S3 bucket. I then created the following Lambda function:

```
// ----receive function----v
function get_json(url, callback) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            var response = JSON.parse(body);
            // call function ----v
            callback(response);
        });
    });
}

var mydata = get_json("https://s3.amazonaws.com/scrollablelist/scrollableList.json", function (resp) {
    console.log(resp);
});
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "http is not defined",
  "errorType": "ReferenceError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:20:18)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)"
  ]
}
```

The Log Output says this:

```
START RequestId: 516f164b-7ee3-11e7-97a7-0373caaf493b Version: $LATEST
module initialization error: ReferenceError
    at get_json (/var/task/index.js:3:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:20:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
END RequestId: 516f164b-7ee3-11e7-97a7-0373caaf493b
REPORT RequestId: 516f164b-7ee3-11e7-97a7-0373caaf493b  Duration: 80.81 ms          Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install npm package for http in your project folder. Please follow below steps,

a. Open node command prompt

b. Navigate (CD ) to your project folder

c. Type command "npm init" if you don't have a package.json file already

e. Type command "npm install http --save" (Which will add http module to package.json)

f. At the beggining of you js file you using "http" please refer http moduleas  below,

var http = require("http");

g. Add package.json file as well in the .zip to upload to Lambda (You don't need to include node modules folder)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the http module. `npm install --save http`

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/

Comment: Thanks, but where do I put that line of code? I'm trying to be serverless.